# Phase register in phase accumulator

Tags: register

In the following flow diagram:

[image]

Is the "phase register" a one-bit register? What does it basically do with that summation mark? What type of register is it? I basically do not know what the phase accumulator do as well but for that I need to understand what phase register is doing first.

Answer (score 1):

It is an N bit register that serves in combaination with the adder at the input to integrate the frequency tuning word (Phase being the integral of frequency after all).

If you look at the diagram you can clearly see that on each clock the register will be loaded with the modulus 2^N sum of its old output and the FTW.

In real parts N is quite often larger then the address range of the ROM (32 or even 48 bits is not uncommon), and various phase dithering and Taylor series approximations are used to improve the spurious performance.

Comment: "Phase being the integral of frequency " I dont understand that part. Isnt the phase increment "2*pi / N" where N is sample per period? What do you mean by phase here?

Answer (score 1):

The way the phase accumulator works in Direct Digital Synthesis is that every clock cycle on fclk, the frequency tuning word is added to the phase register.

For example, assume the phase register starts at 0 and the frequency word is 5.
After the first fclk pulse the phase register become equal to 5. After the second clock pulse, the phase register becomes 10. This continues for every clock pulse

The size of the phase register and tuning word depends on the size of Sine ROM and the accuracy you need to achieve in your waveform. Larger register will have more accuracy in determining the frequency that you can run at.

[Here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9833.pdf) is a link to a datasheet for a DDS integrated circuit. Page 11 and 12 go into the theory of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

The `phase-register` is an `n` bit width register as can be seen on the in/out-puts. The [DDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesis) can outputs arbitrary periodic function. Your example outputs a sine wave, but you can replace the `sine ROM` to an arbitrary function. The `phase-register` stores the actual phase of the periodic function.

What type? The register can be implemented as an n-bit width [D-FF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#D_flip-flop).

The phase accumulator can be interpreted as a *frequency integrator*. Note, that the phase is the integrate of the frequency, and the sum is the discrete equivalent of the integration.

[image]

t=φ/2π

Where the *φ* is the [phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)) the *ω* is the [angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency), the *t* is the [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time) and the *f* is the [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency).

Comment: What is meant by the "phase of the function"?

Comment: Phase accumulator is integrating what actually?

Comment: The phase (`phi`) is the `x` axis, measured in radian. If you know the period time (or the frequency) you can convert the phase to time. `phi = 2pi/f` or `t=2pi/phi`

Comment: Can you show me what do you mean by phi in this context?

Comment: The phi is the phase

Comment: I have never in my life saw such equations I dont know where they come from t = integral of f dx. I know what all these concepts mean you linked to Wikipedia. But the two formulas where the integral of angular freq. with respect to x ? dx? what is x? time is the integral of  frequency?? where how all are derived? Im completely puzzled.

Comment: I have fixed the formula. The integral can be imagined as a multiplication. Lets use a constant frequency function. In this case the phase will increment evenly. The larger the frequency, the faster the phase changes. The case is the same in the integral too. I suggest to clarify and be familiar with the integral first.